# Output Name Field is DIfferent With the Output without Name Field MYSQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT users.id as uid,   projects.id as pid
            FROM users  
            inner join usergroup on usergroup.id = users.user_group
            inner join bookings on bookings.agent_id = users.id 
            inner join units on bookings.unit = units.id
            inner join types on types.id = units.types_id 
            inner join projects on projects.id = types.project_id
            WHERE bookings.status = 'Accepted' AND units.status = 'Sold'
            GROUP BY  pid
```

with the query above, i get the correct and logic output:

```
pid   |   uid
1          1
2          1
9          12
10         14
```

then i want to show the user's name, so i added 1 field in query as shown below:

```
SELECT users.id as uid,  users.f_name, projects.id as pid
            FROM users  
            inner join usergroup on usergroup.id = users.user_group
            inner join bookings on bookings.agent_id = users.id 
            inner join units on bookings.unit = units.id
            inner join types on types.id = units.types_id 
            inner join projects on projects.id = types.project_id
            WHERE bookings.status = 'Accepted' AND units.status = 'Sold'
            GROUP BY  pid
```

but i got a different output for uid:

```
pid    |    uid
1            1
2            1
9            9
10           11
```

This is not logic and anyone know why? Let's assume both are correct but why will output different result?

Comment: the 2 queries are different I see. you have some conditions inside the `ON` in the second query while you don't have these in the first.

Comment: @CodeBird sorry guys, i pasted wrong queries. :) updated queries in questions

Comment: may you create a sqlfiddle to check it....

Comment: @ZafarMalik http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/086d8/7 no prob at all. @_@ remove the comment is you want to test for 2nd query.

Comment: @hahahaha: sqlfiddle is providing same results for both queries..plz create same scenario as you are getting different results.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd query you are filtering data with join condition before where condition while in 1st query you are filtering data just in where clause...keep you 2nd query same as 1st to get same results....

try below query-

```
SELECT projects.id as pid, users.id as uid, users.f_name
            FROM users  
            inner join usergroup on usergroup.id = users.user_group
            inner join bookings on bookings.agent_id = users.id 
            inner join units on bookings.unit = units.id  
            inner join types on types.id = units.types_id 
            inner join projects on projects.id = types.project_id
            WHERE bookings.status = 'Accepted' AND units.status = 'Sold'
            GROUP BY  pid
```

Comment: sorry sorry! i pasted wrong queries :D updated queries in question.

Answer (score 0):

One project ID can be associated to many units and each unit with many bookings and hence with many users. You group by project ID, but you don't specify which of all associated users you want to see for a project ID. You would do this with an aggregate function such as MIN(users.id), MAX(users.id), etc. But you don't use such function, thus telling MySQL: "just give me randomly one of the matching users".

As long as you keep your query as is, it seems that MySQL always gives you the same users, maybe the first it finds. This is by no way guaranteed; you could just as well get different users with the same query.

Now that you changed your query, MySQL goes another route and picks different matching users.

Comment: what i changed was add 1 field to show the name. why it will change the route?

Comment: Yes, it may, because now MySQL needs to read the user table where it was sufficient before to read the index. Anyway, as you tell the DBMS "give me one line per product, each with one of its associated users randomly picked" you get what you ask for; a user randomly picked. Why does it even bother you that the second query picks different users? You are not interested in which user gets picked. Or are you? Then you should tell the DBMS which one.